# how can I create a graphics object in java?

Tags: java, image, graphics

Hi I'm trying to generate an image with java

```
int width = 640; int height= 480;
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g2 =  image.getGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(path+index+".png"));
```

I'm expecting a blue image... but it's black.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's black instead of blue because `clearRect` fills the rectangle with the **background color**, which is not the color that you set with `setColor`.

The API documentation of `clearRect` says:

> Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface. This operation does not use the current paint mode.
>
> Beginning with Java 1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. **Applications should use `setColor` followed by `fillRect` to ensure that an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color.**

So, use `fillRect` instead of `clearRect`.

```
g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics::clearRect()` does *not* use the current Color (or rather: Paint).

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color
>   of the current drawing surface. This operation does not use the
>   current paint mode.

Solution: use `fillRect()` instead.